# SSH and SSHPASS Condition if machine online or offline

Tags: ssh

I need to make bash file for remote backups. If remote machine is down i would like to send reminder by email. So this script needs to test if remote machine has ssh on if so do backup, otherwise send mail.

```
sshpass -p pass ssh -l root $host
this give me connection timed out if remote machine is down and ok wheen it is online

1condition, do it when machine is on
.....rsync backup....

2condition, do it wheen machine is down
...sending mail....
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over-complicating this; what you really care about is the *backup* -- and if it succeeds or fails.

Try this:

```
rsync -avz /local/path root@$host:/remote/path || echo "failed" | mail -s "Backup failed" username@machine
```

The important part is the `||` that executes the remainder of the line if the exit code from the `rsync` command indicates failure -- for any reason.

Comment: Thank you, how to send email if rsync has executed properly ?

Comment: You can also add `&& echo success | mail -s "Backup succeeded" username@machine` to the command line and it'll work as you want. (Try `false && echo success || echo failure` and `true && echo success || echo failure` to convince yourself that the right thing happens with both success and failure.)